# rotate a string n characters to the left, except the special characters

Tags: python, string, for-loop

Hi I need help rotating a string to the left n amount of times, I have done so: btw Strings is a list of strings:

```
 finaltext = ""
 for i in strings:
    first = i[0 : n] 
    second = i[n :] 
    i = second + first
    finaltext += i
```

However,  i'm not sure how to do this so that in a given string, say: "The intern", the space or any special characters would not move.

```
s1 = "The intern"
```

Right now my output is: 
    `ternThe in`

output I want:
 `ern eThein`

any ideas? I currently created a function that indicates when a special character and its index in a string, I used that in a for loop to know that the current character is a special character, but when it comes to rotation how would i avoid that character

Comment: Your question is asking for help with problem analysis and solution design, rather than a SO-type question.  You've already identified what you need to do; how would you carry that out with pencil & paper?

Comment: I'm asking a question because I'm stuck, I've already tried the logic and having trouble implementing that. All i'm asking is for some direction not the coded answer...

Comment: Create a string with only the characters to be rotated, and a data-structure to hold those that cannot be rotated with the given positions. Rotate and insert.

Comment: why is the output `ern eTheint`? before the second work contain 6 characters, after your function it changes to 7 ?

Comment: For your given example, does rotation `n=7`? Also what is the definition of a "special" character?

Comment: @Mr_U4913 sorry that was a typo. Fixed now, rotation was 6 to the left

Comment: special character is anything that isn't in the alphabet, like punctuation

Comment: "Some direction" is not a specific programming question; it's out of scope for Stack Overflow.  Again, please refer to the link in my first comment.

Comment: @DanielMesejo thanks, I figured it out!

Comment: @Prune In the time you typed up the 3rd comment someone already gave me the answer I was looking for LOL. I'll keep in mind what you said about asking specific questions, but sometimes someone needs a little clarity. That's all :)

Comment: Happy to help, but in you expected output `ern eThein`, it's not obvious to me why the space has shifted and where the extra `e` next to `T` came from.

Comment: @pylang, Hi, I think it's because the space is seen as a character and thus when I rotated it, everything got shifted to the left. I figured out how to do it though, so it's all good!

Answer (score 1):

An intriguing question.  How to rotate a string while ignoring specific characters?

Here we *remove, rotate, reinsert* characters.

**Given**

```
import collections as ct


def index(s):
    """Return a reversed dict of (char, [index, ...]) pairs."""
    dd = ct.defaultdict(list)
    for i, x in enumerate(s):
        dd[x].append(i)
    return dd


s1 = "The intern"
s2 = "Hello world!"
```

**Code**

```
def rotate(s, n=0, ignore=""):
    """Return string of rotated items, save ignored chars."""
    s0 = s[:]

    # Remove ignored chars
    for ig in ignore:
        s = s.replace(ig, "")

    # Rotate remaining string, eqiv. to `res = s[-n:] + s[:-n]`
    tail = s[-n:]
    head = ""

    for c in s[:-n]:         
        head += c    
    res = tail + head


    # Reinsert ignored chars
    if ignore:
        res = list(res)
        lookup = index(s0)
        for ig in ignore:
            for idx in lookup[ig]:
                res.insert(idx, ig)
        res = "".join(res)
    return res
```

**Tests**

```
assert rotate(s1, n=0, ignore="") == "The intern"
assert rotate(s1, n=1, ignore="") == "nThe inter"
assert rotate(s1, n=1, ignore=" ") == "nTh einter"
assert rotate(s1, n=3, ignore=" ") == "ern Theint"

assert rotate(s2, n=12, ignore="") == "Hello world!"
assert rotate(s2, n=1, ignore="") == "!Hello world"
assert rotate(s2, n=1, ignore="H !") == "Hdell oworl!"
assert rotate(s2, n=1, ignore="!") == "dHello worl!"
```